# sicktoolbox installation

Tags: ros, sicktoolbox-wrapper

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have tried to install sicktoolbox on ROS, but I really do not know how to do it?!!!

First I have installed the sicktoolbox as described on the   "The Sick Lidar Matlab/C++ Toolbox - A Quick Start Guide". It works in all examples.

After that my intention was to install the toolbox on ROS.

A can´t make the rosmake step, because it nevers found the sicktoolbox package.

May I put the sicktoolbox in a proper directory?
Like (my_installation_dir)/ros/diamondback/stacks/sicktoolbox   !!!

Where is rosmake searching for the packages? OR how can I do it?

And the sicktoolbox_wrapper, is it created by rosmake?

All that can be stupid question, but I cann´t overcome this...

Can anyone give me all the steps.

Thanks for you help.
Daniel

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30484/sicktoolbox-installation/) by [dcastro](https://answers.ros.org/users/1880/dcastro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-03-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cybodroid](https://answers.ros.org/users/25023/cybodroid/) on 2016-03-24**:
When I tried to install Sick Lidar Matlab/C++ toolbox I got errors, lot of them. Probably something is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First, check that your `$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` is [set up correctly](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment).

If it is, you should be able to `roscd` to `sicktoolbox`.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2